# Source is producing too many agents

Tags: anylogic

My arrival rate for my source is in hours, and I am using events to set it's rate to a distribution at different times, sourceShoppers.set_rate(triangular(1, 5, 2));. However, the source is producing roughly 3 per second, as opposed to an average of 2 an hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this:
self.set_rate(triangular(1,5,2), PER_HOUR);

Nevertheless, when you do that, notice that you will get a random sample for the triangular distribution, which will set the rate to be for instance 1.2 per hour in which case the arrivals will follow a poisson distribution with an average of 1.2 per hour always unless you change the rate again...

If you want some advice, you have to say what you want to achieve...